# Get product collection in Magento2 root file

Tags: magento2

I need product collection In my root file so

How can I get the product collection in my root file in Magento2?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below code in your root file.

```
<?php

error_reporting(1);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
use \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$instance = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$state = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');
$product_collections = $instance ->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
$collections = $product_collections->create();
foreach ($collections as $product) {
    print_r($product->getData());     
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this path in root directory in magento2.4.3

```
require __DIR__ . '/../app/bootstrap.php';
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use Bootstrap to run Application which will return you response object. Here is official example from index.php file:

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
$params = $_SERVER;
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'website2';
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website';
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);

$app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Http');
$bootstrap->run($app);

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();   
$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection');
/** Apply filters here */
$productCollection->load();
?>
```

Hope this helps.